# Is updating Bean property in filter possible?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlet-filters

Lets say i am redirecting to some jsp. The request goes through the filter(class that extends `javax.servlet.Filter`) in Spring. Now in that filter i'd like to set some bean properties with values from cookie that came with request. Afterwards when request passes filter i would like to use that bean properties in the jsp I was redirecting to. I've been trying to make it work for a while but wasn't successful. I am able to get the bean in the filter so I call setter, but when that jsp loads I can see only the default preset value and not the one that came in the cookie. Is something like this even possible? (I will add code snippets if needed.)

Comment: Won't this be a bad idea? Because you will be making the bean stateful. Instead, write something which gets that value and puts it in an appropriate place from where you can get it in JSP.

Comment: i'm open to any solution. :) I just need an object that would be accessible from every jsp. And that i could set the properties in the filter with values from the cookie. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: Please post what all you have tried.

Comment: Meanwhile i managed to get it work by saving the values from cookie into session. It seem to work fine yet.

Comment: Ya, that is a good way, I would say also you can get the request object in any of the class you need using this code " HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder

        .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();" using this also you can get the cookie value or simply you have to do @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request above spring 3 with a singleton spring bean, you will get the request object injected there, but for your use-case I prefer the first way  to get the object from the RequestContextHolder.